# Command to make a Python application open a webpage

Tags: python, browser, syntax-error, html, python-2.7

What would I have to do to make a Python application I am writing open up a web page in the default browser? It doesn't need to be told what the webpage is or anything, it'll be opening one that I've already chosen.

I found some documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) but I always get a syntax error from the symbols in the URL. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL needs to be in a string.

```
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I feel so stupid now. Blame the lack of sleep. >.<

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `webbrowser` module.